# Is the dipole moment of a polarized particle supposed to be a constant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, polarization, dipole-moment

> Problem $4.4$ A point charge $q$ is situated a large distance $r$ from a neutral atom of polarizability $\alpha$. Find the force of attraction between them.

Source: Griffiths, Electrodynamics

---

Textbook solution:

$
\text { Field of } q: \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{q}{r^{2}} \hat{\mathbf{r}} \text { . Induced dipole moment of atom: } \\ \mathbf{p}=\alpha \mathbf{E}=
\frac{\alpha q}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0} r^{2}} \hat{\mathbf{r}}
$
Field of this dipole, at location of $q(\theta=\pi$, in Eq. $3.103): E=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{1}{r^{3}}\left(\frac{2 \alpha q}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0} r^{2}}\right)$ (to the right). Force on $q$ due to this field: $\quad F=2 \alpha\left(\frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}}\right)^{2} \frac{1}{r^{5}}$ (attractive).

---

What I have tried:

$\textbf{p} = \alpha \textbf{E}$

the potential due to the induced dipole is:
$V_{\mathrm{dip}}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{\mathbf{p} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^{2}} = (\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}})^2 \frac{\alpha q}{r^{4}}$

However, why isn't $E = - \frac{\partial V_{dip}}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}})^2 \frac{\alpha q}{r^{4}} = (\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}})^2 \frac{4 \alpha q}{r^{5}}$, which is larger than the answer given by a factor of 2?

The author appears to take $p$ as a constant, thus it is somehow left out of the partial derivative.

Thus my questiom is

> Is dipole moment, in this case, supposed to be a constant?

Comment: I think you are right about the text assuming that the dipole does not change. You want the field at a point; the gradient of the potential (-kp/$r^2$) at that point when q is at that location. For the gradient you are changing r in the potential but not the distance to q.

Comment: @R.W. Bird I think I understand. The gradient of the potential reflects the change in E when a test charge moves around, while the point charge q remains where it is (therefore dipole moment does not change)! Thanks!

P.S. maybe you should put your comment in your answer too...

Answer (score 1):

I found the net force on the dipole and it agrees with the answer from the text (using a binomial approximation). I think you have an extra factor of 2 in your expression for the potential energy. Be careful that you don't confuse the dipole charge with the external charge.

Comment: Would you elaborate a bit more on why I have an extra factor of 2 in the expression for potential energy? Also, would you show your approach (at least briefly), it will be of much help :) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was reading the exponent as a multiplier.

Comment: The force on the dipole (or the charge q) is: F = $(kQq/{r ^2)}[(1 + a/r)^{-2} – (1 – a/r)^{-2}]$.  Where the dipole has charges +Q and -Q separated by 2a, and k = 1/(4π$ε_o$). Using $(r + a)^{-2} = [r(1 + a/r)]^{-2} = (1/r^2)(1 – 2a/r)$ from the binomial expansion, Then: F =  $(kQq/{r^2})(4a/r) = 2kqp/{r^3} = (2kq/{r^3})(αkq/{r^2})$.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct. The force is the gradient of the potential energy, that is, the rate of change when the charge is moved. This includes the change in polarization.

Comment: So I guess it is an erratum?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is an erratum.